# How to make maps marker title always visible

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-maps, android-event

I want to make the markers title always visible
When I use

```
marker.showInfoWindow();
```

it only works on the fist opened map
when user drag the map to another marker it will be without title.

is there ant way I can make it visible all the time?

If not

then user has to click on the marker to see the title, in that case which event I have to use to make the user go to another activity when click the marker
I mean user should double click or long click the marker to go to the details activity, but there is no double click or long click events for the marker.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of Google Maps only supports 1 open info window. That is why the second marker is without title.

As for the second part of your question:

The default I use is that when the user clicks an marker there is an info window shown. 
When the user clicks the marker for a second time the info window closes. And when the user clicks the info window it opens the detail activity.

Some useful events you can receive:

- [OnInfoWindowClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener.html)
- [OnMapClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener.html)
- [OnMapLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener.html)
- [OnMarkerClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener.html)
- [OnMarkerDragListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener.html)

Comment: Thanks mate, OnInfoWindowClickListener did the job